# What are the different indicators to measure historical volatility for stocks on individual basis?

Tags: volatility, equities, technical-analysis

Google search shows there are three indicators to measure volatility: 1. Average True Range 2. Standard Deviation / Variance 3. Bollinger Bands.

What are the indicator(s) that you use to identify the market phase on the basis of volatility or how do you quantify volatility apart from the above-listed parameters for equity?